# Syntax problem in LaTeX

Tags: fonts

I am a beginner in LaTeX and I am using TeXworks. It will be a great help if anyone can tell me what is the wrong with the code below.

```
\textsc{
{\large Report submitted in the partial fullfilment of dual degree in\\} 
{\bfseries Agricultural and Food Engineering\\}
 \ with specialization in\\
 {\bfseries {Agricultural Systems and Management}
 }
```

Comment: The closing curly brace of `\textsc{...` is missing. Or remove the starting curly brace between `\bfseries` and `Agricultural`.

Answer (score 1):

As say Heiko Oberdiek in his comment, you have unbalanced curly braces. Beside this, you have unnecessary twice `\bfseries` and command for new line is beter put outside grouped text (with `{}`. So your text can be simplified to:

```
\textsc{
{\large Report submitted in the partial fulfilment of dual degree in} \\
{\bfseries  Agricultural and Food Engineering\\
            with specialization in\\
            Agricultural Systems and Management}
        }
```

**Edit:**
Barbara Beeton in his comment warning me, that two `\bfseries` are intentional. I'm sorry for my superficiality in reading question. Considering this, the OP can be as follow:

```
\textsc{
{\large Report submitted in the partial fulfillment of dual degree in} \\
\textbf{Agricultural and Food Engineering}\\
            with specialization in\\
\textbf{Agricultural Systems and Management}
        }
```

Comment: i think it was intentional that "with specialization in" was in normal weight, not bold.

Comment: @barbarabeeton,I see now, Apparently I overlooked this. I will upgrade my answer.